# (Ubuntu) C Computing CPU usage using /proc/stat

Tags: c, cpu-usage

I'm trying to write a program in C that will read from /proc/stat, wait a second, then read from /proc/stat again a second later, then do some math to find the "current" CPU usage, as well as the usage for each core. I think that the easiest way to do this is to save the results of /proc/stat to a file, as well as a second file for the second "state" of /proc/stat. I would then read from it and calculate from there. For some reason, though, I have no clue why neither of my files are being created.

```
int main() {
    FILE *state0;
    FILE *state1;
    state0 = fopen("/proc/stat", "w+");
    delay();
    state1 = fopen("/proc/stat", "w+");

    char *con0 = malloc(500);
    fprintf(state0, con0);

    fclose(state0);
    fclose(state1);

    return 0;
}
```

And help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can always just `frewind` usually. The data is generated *at the time of read* so you must read in advance, then wait.

Comment: `"w+"` mode is "append" which makes no sense for this. You want `"r"`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, when you try to save a file by calling:

```c
fprintf(state0, con0);
```

You're trying to write the memory allocated at `con0` to `state0`, which is a pointer to `/proc/stat`.

This of course fails because you don't have permissions to write to `/proc/stat`, which you shouldn't.

To open these files for reading, as tadman mentioned, you want to open the files in `"r"` mode:

```
FILE *state0;
FILE *state1;
state0 = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
delay();
state1 = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
```

What you'd want to do is create a separate file, for example:

```c
FILE *newfile;
newfile = fopen("/tmp/procstattemp", "w");
```

and write to this file using:

```c
fprintf(newfile, con0);
```

Also, you're allocating memory for `con0`, but you haven't written anything to this buffer.
If you want to save `/proc/stat` to a file, you'll need to read the file and copy it into `con0` before writing your temporary file.

See also:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/